# Discord bot is not responsive

Tags: discord

I am trying to make an AI bot, and the bot is even online in the server but it doesn't respond to commands
I've double checked the bot token, open ai token and all that stuff still the bot doesn't respond, it does have necessary perms (ADMIN PERMS)

I've fixed all the other errors issues, and I've installed the necessary imports

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import openai
import os
import requests

# Set up Discord bot
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.messages = True
intents.typing = True
intents.presences = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

# Set up OpenAI API key
openai.api_key = os.getenv("openai")


# Event handler for when the bot is ready
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"We have logged in as {bot.user}")


@bot.event
async def on_command(ctx):
  print(f"Command invoked: {ctx.command} with args: {ctx.args}")


# Command to generate a story
@bot.command(name="generate_story", help="Generate a story based on a prompt.")
async def generate_story(ctx, *, prompt):
  response = generate_text(prompt, engine="text-davinci-003", max_tokens=150)
  await ctx.send(f"Generated Story:\n```\n{response}\n```")


# Command to generate a concept
@bot.command(name="generate_concept",
             help="Generate a concept based on a prompt.")
async def generate_concept(ctx, *, prompt):
  response = generate_text(prompt, engine="davinci-codex", max_tokens=50)
  await ctx.send(f"Generated Concept:\n```\n{response}\n```")


def generate_text(prompt, engine, max_tokens):
  url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/" + engine + "/completions"
  headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": f"Bearer {openai.api_key}",
  }

  data = {
      "prompt": prompt,
      "max_tokens": max_tokens,
  }

  response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
  return response.json()["choices"][0]["text"].strip()


# Run the bot
discord_bot_token = os.getenv("Botkey")

if discord_bot_token:
  bot.run(discord_bot_token)
else:
  print("Error: Discord bot token not found in environment variables.")
````